# GNU screen close windows when command terminates

Tags: linux, window, gnu-screen, split-screen

I am using screen to show different logs in a split-screen. I would like to un-split the screen automatically when the process ends, or at least switch to the next active window.
Now, when I close a program, the screen remains blank, unless I switch manually to another window or buffer.
Alternatively, is there a way to intercept the CTRL-C and quit screen with that?

Answer (score 0):

One example of a solution would be to use 'eval' to a) navigate to a split and b) 'remove' this split.

Example with two regions above each other, being in the lower and wanting to 'un-split' the upper one. 'sleep' is the process I am waiting for to finish in the upper split:

```
 sleep 5 && screen -X eval 'focus top' 'remove'
```